# Date format change upon update event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, datetime

I'm facing an issue with date formatting. Upon calling up the UpdateItem action, the date format for `CreatedAt` gets messed up. I'm using JSON by the way, so must be something to do with date serialization.

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Create action:

```
public int CreateItem(Item item)
{
    var item = new Item();
    viewModel.CopyToItem(item); 

    item.CreatedBy = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
    item.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

    db.Items.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return item.ItemId;
}
```

Update action:

```
public void UpdateItem(Item item)
{
    item.UpdatedBy = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
    item.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The incorrect date format:

```
/Date(1395366469723)/
```

It should be:

```
2014-03-21T09:50:01.747
```

I tried this in the controller but get a `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'` error.

```
string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
item.CreatedAt = DateTime.ParseExact(isoJson, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ttt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Using non-nullable `DateTime` in the model didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). If you are wanting to get a DateTime object with the given javascript date value, create a new DateTime object from 1/1/1970 and then add the milliseconds.

Observe:

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(1395366469723);

// "21/03/2014 1:47:49 AM"
```